# SQL Join to only one record in one to many relationship

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT c.[ClientID]
        ,u.[AccessId]
 FROM [tblClient] c
 INNER JOIN [tblUser] u ON u.[Id] = c.[UserId]
```

This tblUser has multiple ID's for each UserID row.

So it would look like this:

```
UserID    AccessID
1           AD2F0A-965B78414-2B34906F2-0127AA5A
1           ID2F0A9-65B784-142B34906-F20127AA5A
1           UD2F0A9-65B78-4142B34906F-20127AA5A
2           TD2F0A9-65B784142-B34906F-20127AA5A
2           RD2F0A9-65B784142B3-4906-F20127AA5A
3           WD2F0A96-5B784142-B34906F201-27AA5A 
3           ZD2F0A96-5B784-142B34-906F2-0127AA5A
3           CD2F0A965-B784142B3-4906F20-127AA5A
```

Is there a way to only get the top(or 1) AccessId for each UserID? It doesnt matter which AccessID i get, I just want 1 of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT c.[ClientID], MAX(u.[AccessId]) 
    FROM [tblClient] c 
        INNER JOIN [tblUser] u 
            ON u.[Id] = c.[UserId]
    GROUP BY c.[ClientID]
```

Comment: Sorry this was a bad example. My u.AccessId is actually a UniqueIdentifier

Comment: @User - it still works.  The code basically says "give me the top accessid for each userid, and only one row per userid"

Comment: I get the following: Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for max operator.

Comment: Sorry you can do `MAX(CAST(AccessID as Varchar))`